# What is a better way to do this simple filter with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, filter

I am learning jQuery I made a simple selection filter with a basic knowledge with the purpose of learning new techniques.
My question is, what is a better maybe more complex way to do this: 
https://codepen.io/frivolta/pen/LLwjjy

```
$(".elementFilter li").on("click",eventTrigger);

function eventTrigger(){
  var getFilterName = $(this).attr("class");
  if(getFilterName!="all"){
  $(".elementList li:not([data-category='"+getFilterName+"'])").hide(); 
  $(".elementList [data-category='"+getFilterName+"']").show();
  }else{
     $(".elementList li").show();
  }
}


<div class="elements">
  <ul class="elementFilter">
    <li class="all">Show all</li>
    <li class="filterOne">Filter One</li>
    <li class="filterTwo">Filter Two</li>
    <li class="filterThree">Filter Three</li>
    <li class="filterFour">Filter Four</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="elementList">

    <li data-category="filterOne">Filter One</li>
    <li data-category="filterTwo">Filter Two</li>
    <li data-category="filterThree">Filter Three</li>
    <li data-category="filterFour">Filter Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to separate functions and passing parameters between them, if you have any advice I would be glad to hear that.
Thanks,
F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost fine but it will not run if you change add some other class in li elements. See my code below. I showed the problem with the solution.

```
$(".elementFilter li").on("click",eventTrigger);

function eventTrigger(){
  var isClasssAll = $(this).hasClass("all");
  var getFilterName = $(this).attr("data-category");

  if(!isClasssAll){
  $(".elementList li:not([data-category='"+getFilterName+"'])").hide(); 
  $(".elementList [data-category='"+getFilterName+"']").show();
  }else{
     $(".elementList li").show();
  }
}



<div class="elements">
  <ul class="elementFilter">
    <li class="all asdasd">Show all</li>
    <li data-category="filterOne" class="filterOne 1">Filter One</li>
    <li data-category="filterTwo" class="filterTwo 2">Filter Two</li>
    <li data-category="filterThree" class="filterThree 3">Filter Three</li>
    <li data-category="filterFour" class="filterFour 4">Filter Four</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="elementList">

    <li data-category="filterOne">Filter One</li>
    <li data-category="filterTwo">Filter Two</li>
    <li data-category="filterThree">Filter Three</li>
    <li data-category="filterFour">Filter Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: About that, what if I put more classes on the filter, for example<li class="filterOne filterTwo">Filter One</li> it won't work too

Comment: Fine. If you see any other better and faster way to solve what you posted please share.

Comment: If you dont see any other better way cilonsider my sugeested code selected answer. Ty